# How to add layers with different zoom levels to the layer group in geoserver?

Tags: gis, zooming, layer, geoserver, wms

How to add layers with different zoom levels to the layer group in geoserver?
For example,
layer1 - zoom level 5-8,
layer2 - zoom level 9-12

How to set the layers different zoom levels in geoserver?

Can you help me this issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Layer Groups don't care about your visibility settings so you can add all of them together.

If what you are actually asking is how to make a layer only visible at some zoom levels? then you need to add `<MinScaleDenominator>` and `<MaxScaleDenominator>` to your SLD (or other styling method) - see the [sld cookbook](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld/cookbook/points.html#zoom-based-point) for an example.

Comment: I did it as you say, but the transition between layers is not very smooth. Is there any other way?

Comment: so long as you use the same number in each layer tansition it should be fine